# Reactjs - Playing audio files from outer folder in local machine

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am working on React and want to play audio file in local machine from outer folder.

Here is path where my react folder is located:
"F:\htdocs\avatargfslive2\phoneSystem\reactphonecore"

Here is path where my audio folder is located:
"F:\htdocs\cdr\phone_cdr\2019-10-12\monitor"

Now I want to play the audio files from this audio folder path:

Here is my reactjs code:

```
class BSTable extends React.Component{


  playAudio() {
    console.log("Inside play audio:");
    const audioEl = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0]
    audioEl.play()
  }
  render() {
    
    var cdrdata2 =  this.props.cdrdata.map((data,index)=>{
     return(
       <tr key = {index} style={{display:'table',width:'100%',backgroundColor:'white'}}>
         {/* <td width = "%" key = {index}></td> */}
        <td width = "11.3%" >{`${data.uniqueid}`}</td>
        <td width = "10%">{`${data.userfield}`}</td>
        <td width = "10%">{`${data.caller_number}`}</td>
        <td width = "10%">{`${data.callee_number}`}</td>
        <td width = "10%">{`${data.action_type}`}</td>
        <td width = "10%">{`${data.start_time}`}</td>
        <td width = "10%">{`${data.call_time}`}</td>
        <td width = "10%">{`${data.talk_time}`}</td>
        <td width = "9.4%">
        <button onClick={this.playAudio}>
          <span>Play</span>
        </button>
        <audio className="audio-element">
          <source src="F:/htdocs/cdr/phone_cdr/2020-05-12/monitor/auto-1589470814-367-7865290090.wav"></source>
        </audio>
        </td>
      </tr>  
        
     )  
     
    })
}
```

Tried specifying path in audio source folder:

But it displays error:

**Not allowed to load local resource: file:///F:/htdocs/cdr/phone_cdr/2020-05-14/monitor/auto-1589470814-367-7865290090.wav**

Any solutions for this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - Workaround solution :)

Run this in terminal:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\google\chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Replace the path that match the location of `chrome.exe`.

---

Alternatively, run a server for the file:

Install if you don't have

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Go to the root folder of the file and type:

```
http-server ./
```

Use the source (Replace the port that http-server is running on)

```
<source src="http://localhost:8080/auto-1589470814-367-7865290090.wav"></source>
```

Comment: Thanks. will check it.